# Make picture not accessabel

Tags: image, hide

New laws forces us NOT to show pictures in our shop.
I need some way to find a secure folder, so that only buyers in our shop see the picture.
To prefend google to find them, i can make a robot  disallow in htacces.
How can i make/find any script that only the picture from a product shows up if customers had send in the order and paid for?...or if they are in our domain on the product page? I have no ideas where to start. I was thinking about publishing a picture in cgi-bin with a login-passw acces on request. The law is from Brussel and will hit us as of januari (everyone with smokestuff and e-cigarettes)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What you're asking is *very* broad.  We're not at all aware of what technologies you're using, what code you have, or anything about your application.  In general if something needs to be published on the internet but shouldn't be publicly accessible then you would require user authentication/authorization before displaying that content.  But that's probably about as specific as we can get given the information present.  Note also that Stack Overflow does not offer any legal advice nor any guarantees that solutions found here will meet your legal obligations.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i understand. The only way then is indeed user pass and login. Will search for that. The product is legal in 145 countries. Customers needs to have an option to see what they buy, however tobacco gets difficult. In this case its then a server setting script or login script for shared server Apache and not for stackoverflow. However i was hoping someone could point me out in more options then only user authentication. But then it is indeed difficult because its a shopping cart.....lol

Thnx anyway.